# Default value of fields when opening a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, progress-bar, default-value

I have a macro in word for comparing and creating new word documents.
In this script there are a label and a progressbar for showing the progress of the script, I would like to hide this fields and reset the value of these fields when I open the document and I don't know how to do that.

Could you please help with that?

**My script:**

```
Private Sub SummaryReportButton_Click()

    'Initialize the progressbar
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim filesNumber As Integer
    k = 0   
    Me.Label.Caption = "0% Completed"
    Me.ProgressBar.Value = k

    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim objDocB As Word.Document
    Dim objDocC As Word.Document

    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolderA As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFolderB As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFolderC As Scripting.Folder

    Dim colFilesA As Scripting.Files
    Dim objFileA As Scripting.File

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolderA = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with the original documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    Set objFolderB = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with revised documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    Set objFolderC = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder for the comparisons documents", ThisDocument.Path))

    Set colFilesA = objFolderA.Files

    'Turn off DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    'Number of files in the folder
    filesNumber = objFolderA.Files.Count

    For Each objFileA In colFilesA

    If objFileA.Name Like "*.docx" Then
        Set objDocA = Documents.Open(objFolderA.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name)
        Set objDocB = Documents.Open(objFolderB.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name)
        Set objDocC = Application.CompareDocuments( _
            OriginalDocument:=objDocA, _
            RevisedDocument:=objDocB, _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew)
        objDocA.Close
        objDocB.Close
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Turn off DisplayAlerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

        objDocC.SaveAs FileName:=objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        objDocC.Close SaveChanges:=True

    End If

        'Update the label and the progressbar
        k = k + 1
        Me.ProgressBar.Value = k * 100 / filesNumber
        Me.Label.Caption = k * 100 / filesNumber & "% Completed"

    Next objFileA

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can always comment out all lines referring to required `Label` and `ProgressBar` items. You can also set `Visibility` to `false` by selecting items on UserForm and changing values in `Properties window`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know why but I don't see the proposerty Visibility` when I click on the progressbar and go to the properties. Furthermore when I try to change the property in my macro: `Me.ProgressBar.Visibility = True`, I obtain the error `Object doesn't support this property or method.`

Comment: The property to set should be `Visible` or, possibly, `Hidden`, not "Visibility".

Comment: The error is still the same even if I try with `Me.Label.Visible = true` it's the same on the ProgressBar